# How to get string array from separate single string with multiple matching delimiter?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the below output from this string in C#.

`hi how are you? {Id} any string {Name} can come here {Test}`

The output should be an array of the below strings:

`Id`
`Name`
`Test`

Comment: Use a _Regular Expression_ (`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`)

Comment: Is the surrounding text exactly the same every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *regular expressions* and *Linq*. Assuming that you have *identfiers* within `{...}` and each identifier must start from letter or _ and can contain letters, digits and _ you can put

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "hi how are you? {Id} any string {Name} can come here {Test}";

var result = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"{[\p{L}_][\p{L}\d_]*}")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(item => item.Value.Trim('{', '}'))
  .ToArray();

// Let's have a look:
Console.Write(string.Join(" ", result));
```

**Output:**

```
Id Name Test
```